# why does checking the number a parameter in Ubuntu has always returns false

Tags: linux

I am currently coding in a Ubuntu batch file for my homework and I need to check the amount of parameters I enter when I use it in the console (I.E ./nameOfTheProgram parameter1 parameter 2)

though, For some reason it never returns true, meaning that I can't actually enter into the rest of the program.

I've tried doing it this way, but it doesn't enter the else

```
if [ $# -lt 1 ]
    then
        function1
elif [ $# -gt 1 ]
    then 
        function1
else 
    function2
    function3
fi
```

I've also tried doing

```
if [ $# -eq 1 ]
    then
        function2
        function3
else
    function1
fi
```

Alas it immediately goes into the else statement, whether there is zero, one or two parameter

Hope to get some help on this

Comment: Why don't you just do `echo $#` to see its value?

Comment: I tried, and it gives back the correct value ( I.E zero, one or two) but it still doesn't enter the correct statement appropriate to the answer it gives me

Comment: How did you ascertain that it never returns true? Your snippet works for me (I replaced the function calls with `echo didn't work` and `echo works` respectively and it does exactly what you told it to.

Comment: @tink well, I don`t know if it doesn't return true, but on my end, it simply never calls the function, I tried with echoes as well, just how you did it, but it doesn't work, with these exact snippets of code:

pancakerabbit@ubuntu:~/Documents/TP2$ ./GestionEmployes Data_26-11-21.txt 
it doesn't work
pancakerabbit@ubuntu:~/Documents/TP2$ ./GestionEmployes Data_26-11-21.txt 2
it doesn't work
pancakerabbit@ubuntu:~/Documents/TP2$ ./GestionEmployes 
it doesn't work
pancakerabbit@ubuntu:~/Documents/TP2$

Answer (score 0):

So thank you for the people that answered, I ended up finding what the problem was !

if you put the if statement inside a function the $# will be of the function and not of the program

So be careful with these things, I didn't know Ubuntu worked that way, I am new to it.

Comment: Small correction, this is not a Ubuntu-specific thing. This is how the bash scripting language works generally.

Comment: good to know, thank you ! @anestv